# How do I fix the responsive issue with my text

Tags: html, css, text

I am having a problem with the text on my website and am struggling to find a solution.

This is what I wish for the text to look like, and how it looks on my desktop normally:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZ4o.png

However when I zoom my screen in or look at it on my phone it ends up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E7lu.png

this is the css I have for the text:

```
font-family: 'Bebas';
color: #ce0101;
font-size: 100px; 
font-weight: 400;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 4.45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.52);
transform: scaleY(1.002);
text-align: center;
```

Comment: Are you using position absolutes or floating divs?? Your provided CSS is not the issue.

Comment: What's the line-height?

Comment: @Dave I am using divs.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a line-height issue. Without seeing the site in action I can only suggest

```
line-height: 100px;
```

Comment: I usually do `line-height: 1` so I don't have to change 2 spots if design changes :P

Comment: Have you got a link to the website? I am almost certain this is `line-height` related.

Comment: @Vector I set the line height and it solved the issue of the text stacking on itself, but it still puts the last word of the text down a line. How do I keep all the text on the same line?

Comment: @IceCreamLord `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: You have numerous options on how to tackle that issue. You could use `em` for sizing. If you are more comfortable with `px` then you could simply use a media query to change the text size to `80px` on smaller screens

Comment: @Vector ok I will probably use a media query. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Happy to help. I'm glad this fixed your issue. Just as a side note, don't forget to update your line-height to `80px` also within your media query. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting your [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)?